# CSS opacity property does not work on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

It works on Firefox but on Chrome doesn't. What I'm trying to do is that a card applies the opacity property when hovering on that card.

HTML file:

```
<div class="col mb-4">
        <a class="textoc"href="user/terapeuticos">
          <div class="card carta">
          
            <img src="../../../assets/imagenes/Fondo1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title subtitulo2 text-center rounded">Masajes terapéuticos</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </a>
        
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.textoc:link
{
  
  opacity: 1!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  
}

.textoc:hover
{
  opacity: 0.5!important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  
}

.textoc:visited
{
  color: black;
  
}

.carta
{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #F3329F;
  border-width: 2px;
  
}

.subtitulo2
{
  
  color:#F3329F;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #F3329F;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

I tried to solve it by adding `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` but nothing changed.

Pd: I'm using Boostrap 4 framework.

Comment: the `:link` pseudo selector is unnecessary. `!important` can be omitted as well.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in Chrome, not Firefox, since Safari behaves the same way. I'm not a CSS expert but it could be that `opacity` doesn't make much sense on an `a` tag. It also doesn't work on a `span`. Why not put the whole thing in a `div` and put the opacity and background color on that?

Comment: `opacity` property can be applied to all elements. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what the problem is. Instead of changing the opacity of the a(.textoc) you need to change the opacity of the img that is the child of that a.

```
.textoc img:hover{
 opacity: 0.5;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `.card` within the `.textoc:hover`

```
.textoc:hover .card {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/y906o4s3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display: block` on `.textoc` for Chrome to be able to pick up the changes of opacity. By default in Chrome anchor tag is set to `inline`.

Just suggestion that you don't need `!important` to achieve something in CSS, it [consider bad practice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).